# Leaflet map is blurry when hosted on BlueHost and viewed in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, leaflet

I am producing a leaflet js map. It looks great when I view it locally in any browser. However, when I upload it to BlueHost and view it in Chrome, it becomes slightly blurry. It is fine in Safari.

This problem is the same as this GitHub discussion describes - https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3297. I haven't been able to find leaflet 0.7.2 and I haven't been able to use CSS calc to force a value rounding successfully. Both of these actions were suggested as potential solutions to this problem in the link above.

Does anyone know of a fix for this? I'm not able to provide screenshots because I don't have 10 reputations. But you can see the screenshots in my post on the GitHub discussion referenced above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue "in Chrome that fractional pixel values in size or position could lead to blurry text and some other glitches when applying CSS transforms."

See here for more details:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3297#issuecomment-100318390

This has since been fixed, likely a change by Chrome.